# How to restart app when it's recover from Tombstoned?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When my App is tombstoned, I want restart App again.How to do this?

Thx~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [post](http://fiercedesign.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/windows-phone-mango-tombstoning-and-life-cycle/). It explains all the app life cycle which is mandatory to understand in order to implement. Check it out, and let us know if you have any doubt.

regards,